# Missing debugger types in VS2005

Tags: visual-studio-2005, debugging

I have one computer that is missing the list of manual debugger types.  See the screenshot below.

It has VS2005 SP1.  What could cause this?

[Blank Debugger http://img505.imageshack.us/img505/5240/blankdebuggerki3.png](http://img505.imageshack.us/img505/5240/blankdebuggerki3.png)

Comment: The image is gone; the question no longer makes sense. Voting to close.

Comment: Have you tried to run this command in the Visual Studio command prompt `devenv /ResetSettings` and/or "Reset all settings" in the tools menu?

Answer (score 1):

Are u using express edition or professional one. Because in express edition these are missing.